Se puede usar la palabra "mía" sin un sustantivo como apelación?
mi amigo de America Latina me escribió en la correspondencia "mía", como una palabra separada. ¿se usa esta palabra por separado del sustantivo y qué significa en este caso? ¿o es un error tipográfico?

Es un saludo en una carta o mensaje informal, expresando cariño o amistad. Si lo deseas, puedes añadir tu propio sustantivo: amiga mía, querida mía, ...

In the function of a noun, I  would use it with the article: La mía: esto resuelve  tanto su duda como la mía. In Mexico, there is a radio station  called "La Mía", which  intuitively means "My station" This reinforces the answer that yes, this word can be used in the function of a noun, but then it should be used with an article.
My intuition is that it can be used both with the definite article and indefinite one: A la lista  sus dudas le agrego una mía: ¿Cómo se usa esta palabra?
